# How can i add action to each item on windows phone list (databound app)?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am new to Windows Phone Programming.
How can i add an action to each item on windows phone data-bound app list.

in Android Programming we could add on Click listener to add an action to a button or to a list it
em.How can we do such a thing in windows phone template (data bound app)
her 
i want when i click on a list item it opens another class or do something .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ListBox to display list of data.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.listbox(v=vs.105).aspx

Then you can use its "SelectionChanged" event & perform action which you want.
You can use "SelectedItem" property to check which item is selected by user.

For more details on "LIstBox", refer this article : http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/wp7-listbox-selecteditem